# Any Tools to Catch Silly Mistakes in C Code?

Tags: c, findbugs, lint

I had a nasty typo that wasted my time and my colleague's time, it was something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < blah; i++); // <- I had a semi-colon here, that's the bug!
{
  // Some awesome logic here
}
```

First of all, it's very embarrassing, second thing, I should never repeat this. I'm relatively new to C. In Java, I guess I can use [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) to catch errors like these, what tool should I use for C code? Lint?

Comment: We've had great success with using a baseball bat here. After we catch the first silly mistake, they tend not to make another!

Comment: Ah, the semicolon problem is a recurring problem. An extra one, a missing one; it makes no difference. They all lead to the same pain-in-the-ass search that takes forever and results in "Doh!" and a head slap. I still have it every once in a while.

Comment: You might want to specify platform.  Not all tools will work unchanged on all platforms.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, [PC-Lint](http://www.gimpel.com/) is probably the best tool available.

Comment: But be ready for a *lot* of warnings if the codebase is any kind of size and hasn't been linted already.

Comment: True about a lot of warnings - but they are all configurable individually. So you can turn off anything you need to.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to [Lykathea's PC-Lint suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205911/any-tools-to-catch-silly-mistakes-in-c-code#205919), you can also get better (or at least more) diagnostics if you bump up the warning level of the compiler.  Something like `/W4` or `-Wall`

Though I'm not sure if your particular problem would have been caught with this (MS VC doesn't seem to flag it even with all warnings enabled). I think that's because it's not an uncommon idiom for `for` loops to be empty when the work is done as side effects of the loop control expressions.

Answer (score 4):

A few things that have saved me in the past, from the top of my head:

- Use if **(3 == bla) rather than (bla == 3)**, because if you misspell and type (3 = bla) the compiler will complain.
- Use the **all-warnings** switch. Your compiler should warn you about empty statements like that.
- Use **assertions** when you can and program defensively. Put good effort into making your program fail early, you will see the weaknesses that way.
- Don't try to circumvent any safeguards the compiler or the OS have put in place. They are there for your ease of programming aswell.

Comment: I dislike the `(CONST == var)` convention. It makes the code far less readable. A static analysis tool will make sure you never type `(var = CONST)`.

Answer (score 4):

Also look at [clang static analysis](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/)

Answer (score 3):

I would start by learning about [splint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splint_(programming_tool)) and [gdb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gdb). If you need more advanced, build on these two tools. But they are a good start.

Answer (score 2):

GCC has most of the functionality that Lint has had built in via the [warning flags](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html).

Answer (score 0):

Any good GUI programming environment ("IDE" - Integrated Development Environment) like Eclipse would generate a warning in a case like that.

Answer (score 0):

A good syntax highlighter will make some cases like this more visible.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest seeing if you have the ability to [enforce MISRA standards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MISRA_C). They were written with great thought and many rules that are simple for a compiler to check. For example, A rule I use requires all NOP commands have their own line. This means when you put a ; on the end of a loop statement it will through an error saying that it is not on it's own line.

Answer (score 0):

[QA·C](http://www.programmingresearch.com/qac_main.html) by Programming Research is another good static analysis tool for C.

Answer (score -1):

In this (old) version of [How to Shoot Yourself In the Foot](http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/susan/joke/foot.htm), and in many other versions around the web, *C* is always the language that allows for the simplest procedure. When programming in *C*, you have to remember this and be careful. If you want protection, choose another language.

This saying is [attributed](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq.html#really-say-that) to Bjarne Stroustrup (C++) himself. To (mis)quote:

> "C makes it easy to shoot yourself in the foot"

Comment: the quote i heard was "C makes it easy to shoot yourself in the foot, but with C++ it blows your whole leg off"

Comment: Steven A. Lowe, you're correct - see the Stroustrup link. That is why I wrote "(mis)quote".